# Как объединить два Single в rxjava?

Tags: android, kotlin, rxjava2

Метод `itemDao.findItemsByDetails()` возвращает `Single<List<Int>` после выполнения которого мы начинаем выполнять метод `getItemsByIds()`, который уже возвращает `Flowable<MutableList<Item>>`. При этом мне нужно для каждого элемента списка добавить в него определенные данные из других таблиц. Например, первый `getAllDetailsItems()` возвращает `Single`.

Каким образом мне объединить два результа `Single` такие как `getAllDetailsItems()` и `getAllDescriptions()`

```
override fun findItemsByDetails(listDetails: List<String>, count: Int): Flowable<MutableList<Item>> {
        return itemDao.findItemsByDetails(listDetails, count).flatMapPublisher { list ->
            itemDao.getItemsByIds(list).flatMapIterable { items -> items }.flatMapSingle {
                itemDao.getAllDetailsItems(it.idItem).map { list ->
                    mapper.mapDetailItem(it, list)
                }.toFlowable().toList()
            }
        }
}
```

Знаю что можно использовать zip/zipWith, но не могу довести до ума.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого используется метод **zip**.

```
 Single single1 = getItemsByIds();
 Single single2 = getAllDetailsItems();
 return Single.zip(single1, single2, (b1, b2) -> arregateList(b1,b2));
```

Чтобы задачи выполнялись паралельно single лучше запускать **fromCallable()**

```
 return Single.fromCallable(() -> search(searchText))
             .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
             .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()));
```